# UNNEST in bigquery isn't working, getting "Cannot access field on a value of type ARRAY"

Tags: google-bigquery

Noob to bigquery, but I need to query a simply project I have from crashlytics that dumps into bigquery.

In a perfect world... this query would work as it makes sense to me, but `exceptions` is a more complex type which requires unnesting?

```
SELECT exceptions.exception_message
FROM `rollertoaster-235.firebase_crashlytics.com_rollertoaster_app_ANDROID`
WHERE STARTS_WITH(issue_title, 'MyCrashFile.java') LIMIT 1000
```

The exceptions are defined in the table schema as such:

[image]

All I want to do is get a resulting list of exception_messages, but it does not like the UNNEST. Reading some docs and other SO questions... it looks like I need to "UNNEST". But I get a similar error.

```
SELECT asdf
FROM `rollertoaster-235.firebase_crashlytics.com_rollertoaster_app_ANDROID`,
UNNEST(exceptions.exception_message) AS asdf
WHERE STARTS_WITH(issue_title, 'MyCrashFile.java') LIMIT 1000
```

Error:

```
Cannot access field exception_message on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<type STRING, exception_message STRING, nested BOOL, ...>> at
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to unnest a field within the struct array, not the array itself.  Try something like this, which unnests the array and projects the field of the unnested record/struct:

```
SELECT ex.exception_message
FROM `your.table`,
UNNEST(exceptions) as ex
WHERE STARTS_WITH(issue_title, 'MyCrashFile.java') LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Ah Thank you! So simple. Really appreciate it and thanks for the explanation as well.